# Space in the Bot Prefix

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

is it possible to make a space in the prefix of an server, because I want, that a user can make a ping to my bot as prefix to
Prefix should be:
<@bot.id>                   <- (with space after ping)
how can I make this
My Code is:

```
def get_prefix(client, message):
try:
    with open('./rsc/databases/prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
        prefixes = json.load(f)

    if str(message.guild.id) in prefixes:
        prefix = prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]
        return [str(prefix), '<@!801443216595353642>', "<@!801443216595353642> "]
    else:
        return ["!", '<@!801443216595353642>', "<@!801443216595353642> "]
except:
    return ["!", '<@!801443216595353642>', "<@!801443216595353642> "]
```

If I don't make a space after server name, it works, but with the space not :/

Because if you use TAB to complete the ping, it automatically set the space :/ and so the bot wouldn't get the command ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**

You can use [`commands.when_mentioned_or`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=when_mentioned_or#discord.ext.commands.when_mentioned_or) when creating your bot.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot_prefix = commands.when_mentioned_or('!')

bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run('token')
```

---

**Old method**

You can check every message in the `on_message` event and change the bot mention to the command prefix before processing commands. This is done by checking the start of `message.content` and if it matches to `'<@!botid> '` replace this with the bot prefix.

```py
from discord.ext import commands

bot_prefix = '!'

bot=commands.Bot(command_prefix=bot_prefix)

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('Pong')

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    bot_mention_str = bot.user.mention.replace('@', '@!') + ' '
    bot_mention_len = len(bot_mention_str)

    if message.content[:bot_mention_len] == bot_mention_str:
        message.content = bot_prefix + message.content[bot_mention_len:]

    await bot.process_commands(message)

bot.run('token')
```

Answer (score 1):

With the [`commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html) extension, you can't have spaces in prefixes because your command won't be detected. You'd have to create commands manually with the [`on_message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=on_message#discord.on_message) event:

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    prefix = get_prefix(client, message)
    if message.content.startswith(prefix):
        #Your code
```

Comment: isn't there a other way, for example that the on_message function deleted the space?