# How to get custom prefix with when mentioned

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have been working on a discord.py bot. I have a custom prefix command that returns the prefix as a str but I get an error. Code:

```
def get_prefix(bot, message):
with open('prefixes.json', 'r') as f:
    prefixes = json.load(f)
return prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = commands.when_mentioned_or(get_prefix), help_command=None, intents=intents)
bot.remove_command("help")
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Iterable command_prefix or list returned from get_prefix must contain only strings, not function
```

Comment: seems like you've just made a mistake when copying: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513680/discord-py-prefix-command

`commands.when_mentioned_or` seems to be extra - try removing it.

Comment: Hey @Mahrkeenerh I want to allow the user to @ the bot or use the prefix.

Comment: I see, wasn't familiar with that one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [discord.py commands.when\_mentioned not working with custom prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65386984/discord-py-commands-when-mentioned-not-working-with-custom-prefix)

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh yes but no, I get an error: TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list when trying to run this

Comment: It says, that you need to add a list of prefixes, not just one. So you can try modifying your get_prefix to: `return [prefixes[...]]`

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh you hit the nail on the head, return [prefixes[str(message.guild.id)]] worked for me thanks!

Comment: Answer to use bot mention as prefix: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65941413/space-in-the-bot-prefix/66023638#66023638

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
prefixes = get_prefix
commands.when_mentioned_or(*prefixes)
```

[`when_mentioned_or`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=when_mentioned_or#discord.ext.commands.when_mentioned_or) wants a tuple. If you want to put a list. You need the `*`